# Python install python-ntlm-1.0

Tags: python, ntlm

I downloaded the python-ntlm-1.0.tar.gz and am trying to install.  I extracted the .tar file to its own directory (C:\python-ntlm-1.0) and executed the following command in the command prompt from that directory:

```
C:\python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\setup.py install
```

I get the following output:

```
running install
running build
running build_scripts
error: file 'C:\python-ntlm-1.0\byteyears.py' does not exist
```

I looked for that file and found it in my scripts directory and put the .tar in the scripts directory and tried it again, but it did not actually install it because when I execute my python script I continue to get `ImportError: No module named ntlm.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read up on handling archives.  See the [`tar.gz`](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/15/how-to-create-and-extract-zip-tar-targz-and-tarbz2-files-in-linux/) section of that linked doc.  You've only uncompressed the tar file, not extracted the contained files.

Comment: I tried that put there was not a setup.py file in the gz only the tar in the gz file.  Should there have been?

Comment: There's your problem, clarified the answer.

Comment: Thank you, that was my issue.  Note, I also had to download and install distribute-0.6.21 because it was dependent on setuptools.